# ionic build ios success but it opens nginx error after launching the app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cross-platform

Does anyone have the same issue with ios builds? 
IONIC ios build was successful and I was able to test in a real device, it works great but when I launch in emulators I get nginx error. 
Below are the screenshot and ionic version
[image]

Ionic Info

```
    Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.2
   NodeJS     : v10.13.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.4.1
   OS         : macOS
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Comment: Did you check this part of the documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/#cors

Comment: Yes, it's not cors issue because I was using https and it works in the device. I see one error in the log that socket is already in use.